# Is "$n$ is an integer and $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is an integer" true or false? 

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am working through a suggested exercise

"If $n$ is an integer, $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is not an integer" - I can prove this is false, and I can prove the converse is false, and I can prove the contrapositive is false.

Now the question asks to show the negation and prove it true or false. Since the original is false by counter example $n=0$, I'm assuming the negation should prove true.

The negation of $p \implies q$ is $p \wedge ¬q$, so the negation in this case should be

"$n$ is an integer and $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is an integer" right?

This can be true ($n=0$) or false ($n=1$). So is the statement true or not? I assume not, so then the original is false AND the negation is false? *getting very confused*

Comment: The formula "If $n$ is an integer, [then] $n/n+1$ is not an integer" is actually of the form $\forall n\ (p(n) \to q(n))$; its negation is of the form $\exists n\  (p(n) \wedge\neg q(n))$.

Comment: @Yury "For all n, if n is an integer, then n/n+1 is an integer" so negation is "There exists an integer n such that n/n+1 is not an integer", which is easily shown with n=1. So the negation is true, and my issue was forgetting quantifiers. Am I following you? Right now I find English slightly easier than the math notation.

Comment: You're correct, Henry. We're using quantifiers, here, instead of (rather than in addition to) implications.

Comment: For n = -2, n/n+1 = (-2 / -1) = 1, which is a well-known integer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The statement

> If $n$ is an integer, then $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is not an integer.

is strictly speaking neither true nor false before $n$ is given a concrete value. When you say you proved it to be false, I think what you really proved false is

> For all $n$, if $n$ is an integer, then $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is not an integer.

If you want a negation of this that you can prove true, you will have to negate the entire unfolded claim, giving:

> There exists an $n$ such that $n$ is an integer and $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is an integer.

---

Alternatively you can choose to work with statements containing free variables, but then you have to group them into *three* classes:

A. Those that are always true.

B. Those that are sometimes true and sometimes false.

C. Those that are always false.

Then *both* of

> - If $n$ is an integer, then $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is not an integer.
> - $n$ is an integer and $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is an integer.

(which are negations of each other) belong in group B. When you proved that the first one "is false", what you really proved was just that it is *not* in group A.

Comment: Everybody gave me the prod I needed to sort it out, but this is the most complete and illuminating answer. Thanks Henning.

Comment: Is there a typo there though? In the statements containing free variables, are those two statements really negations of each other?

Comment: @Henry: Oops, there was a "not" missing. Fixed.

Comment: I hereby grant the drive-by downvoter proactive amnesty and pledge that I will not take it personally if he explains what he finds lacking about the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion lies with implicit quantifiers. If you take $P(n)$ to mean $\forall n:P(n)$ then its negation is $\exists n:\lnot P(n)$. You cannot just take the negation under the (implicit) $\forall$ quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

Except in the case when $n=0$ the statement is always false.
I suppose the most simple proof is:

If $n>0$, we know the following is true $0 < \frac{n}{n+1} < \frac{n+1}{n+1}=1$.
On the other hand the integers are Defined as $\mathbb{Z}=\{0,±1,±2,...\}$ So if the statement were true then $\mathbb{Z} = \{...,-1,0, \frac{n}{n+1}, 1, ...\}$ but this isn't the definition of the integers, therefore $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is not an integer unless $n=0$.